# How to update an entity using Entity Framework from Business Layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I my web application structured with 3 layers, controller, business logic and repository.

From the BL layer I am updating an entity with the following code. As you can see I am updating property by property.

I would like to know if there is a better way to do it, removing this manual mapping.

---------------------- CONTROLLER

```
    public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, DeviceDTO dto)
    {
        GaDevice device = Mapper.Map<GaDevice>(dto);
        deviceBLL.Update(id, device);
        return Ok();
    }
```

---------------------- BL

```
    public void Update(int id, GaDevice entity)
    {
        bool hasValidId = GetById(id) != null ? true : false;
        if (hasValidId == true)
        {
            GaDevice device = deviceRepo.GetById(id);
            device.CanNotifyPc = entity.CanNotifyPc; // NOT SURE HERE
            device.CanNotifyPrinter = entity.CanNotifyPrinter;
            device.LocationId = entity.LocationId;
            device.Name = entity.Name;
            device.Note = entity.Note;
            device.OperativeFromTime = entity.OperativeFromTime;
            device.OperativeToTime = entity.OperativeToTime;
            deviceRepo.Update(device );
            deviceRepo.Save();
        }
```

---------------- Repository

```
    public void Update(GaDevice entity)
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried device=entity ???

Comment: in `deviceRepo.Update` you can Attach device before setting the state. BTW, imho, the mapping should be in the Repository, not in the BL. imho always, using Business class in the Domain and in the Repository saves time but increases confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about saving the changes made to the `context` in the `Update()`?
Otherwise, what does your code in the `Save()` do?

```
public void Update(GaDevice entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```